# Calculating Median in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have the following table:

[image]

I want to calculate the median mileage per car in one query (SQLite). How do I do that?

Here's the closest I've come:

```
SELECT Car, Mileage, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Car ORDER BY Mileage) RowNum FROM car_table ORDER BY Car, Mileage;
```

My expected output is:

Car | Median Mileage

Comment: What is your expected output for this sample data?

Comment: My expected output is:

Car | Median Mileage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with window functions ROW_NUMBER(), COUNT() and AVG():

```
SELECT DISTINCT Car,
       AVG(
         CASE counter % 2
           WHEN 0 THEN CASE WHEN rn IN (counter / 2, counter / 2 + 1) THEN mileage END 
           WHEN 1 THEN CASE WHEN rn = counter / 2 + 1 THEN mileage END
         END
       ) OVER (PARTITION BY car) median 
FROM (        
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY car ORDER BY mileage) rn,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY car) counter
  FROM car_table
)
```

Or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Car,
       AVG(CASE WHEN rn IN (counter / 2 + 1, counter / 2 + 1 - (counter % 2 = 0)) THEN mileage END) 
       OVER (PARTITION BY car) median 
FROM (        
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY car ORDER BY mileage) rn,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY car) counter
  FROM car_table
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e98feed32cd00bd64f3bc48cb0ebb5d1).
Results:

| Car | median |
| --- | --- |
| Honda | 11.85 |
| Toyota | 9.8 |

Comment: I came here to answer with an `PERCENTILE_RANK` function, but alas, SQLite only has `PERCENT_RANK`, which gives the relative ranking. Documentation on window-functions, https://sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html

Comment: @MrGumble where did you find PERCENTILE_RANK? Which database supports it?

Comment: admittedly I mixed up some functions, but I was thinking of ms sql's `PERCENTILE_CONT`, which appears to also exist for MariaDB.